Calculating nth permutation with repetition efficiently, with variable number of elements
After a long night of Calculating nth permutation without repetition efficiently, with variable number of elements, I realized I actually want permutations with repetition.
Given the ordered set {a, b, c}, how can I obtain a function that is:
f(0) = a
f(1) = b
f(2) = c
f(3) = aa
f(4) = ab
f(5) = ac
f(6) = ba
f(7) = bb
...

That is, after the permutations of size 1, there comes permutations of size 2, then size 3, etc., to infinity.

I know "permutations with repetition" isn't the correct term, but I don't know what is

If f(x) = y and the set $S$ is {a, b, c}, then given $x = 999$:

subtract the set size $3^1$ ($999 - 3 = 996$) to "complete" all permutations of size 1
repeat this with $3^2$ ($996 - 3^2 = 987$) to "complete" all permutations of size 2
then $3^3$, $987 - 3^3 = 960$
then $960 - 3^4 = 879$
then $879 - 3^5 = 636$
then $636 - 3^6 = -93$. Since this is negative, we have not completed all permutations with repetitions of size 6.

since we repeated 5 times, we have completed all permutations up to size 5.
To get the 636th permutation with repetition of {a, b, c}, convert 636 to base 3 (size of set).
$$636 / 3 = 212\ \mathbf{remainder}\ 0$$
$$212 / 3 = 70\ \mathbf{remainder}\ 2$$
$$70 / 3 = 23\ \mathbf{remainder}\ 1$$
$$11 / 3 = 7\ \mathbf{remainder}\ 2$$
$$3 / 3 = 2\ \mathbf{remainder}\ 1$$
$$1 / 3 = 0\ \mathbf{remainder}\ 2$$
Looking at the remainders, we get 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 0 (reading remainders backward). These correspond to the indices of the ordered set.
Therefore, the 636th permutation with repetition of {a, b, c} of size 6 is c, b, c, b, c, a.
